# Why aren't the Vertices connected?

Tags: vertices

Hello Blender Community,
I have a problem here with my mesh, because I must have accidentally done something wrong. The vertices somehow doubled or tripled themselves in place and they aren't connected anymore as there where supposed to be earlier. My intention is to lift the vertices up to form some kind of "mountains" as seen in the picture, but as shocased here the vertices act like they were independant to each other which wasn't the case. The only thing I know for now is that I've applied a Modifier wrong after experimenting for a bit, yet I don't know which of them caused it. Is it possible to reverse it?

Comment: You can remove the duplicated verts by select all, then press alt+m and choose By Distance.

Comment: thank you, it worked.